# Linux synchronization without polling

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, synchronization, glibc

In principle what I want is very simple.

Two executables `./read` and `./write` respectively read and write from a resource (let's say a file). Using `flock(2)` it is easy to prevent race conditions between arbitrary invocations of `./read` and `./write` at arbitrary times.

The requirement is that each invocation of `./read` contains a snapshot of the resource from a previous invocation, and if the current resource matches the snapshot, `./read` should wait (sleep) until an invocation of `./write` changes the resource.

From what I gather, the program flows of each program should be something like:

```
//read.c
obtain mutex0
  read resource
  is resource same as our snapshot?
    release mutex0 [1]
    sleep until ./write says to wake up [2]
    obtain mutex0
    read resource
  do something with resource
release mutex0

//write.c
obtain mutex0
  change resource in some way
  tell any sleeping ./read's to wake up
release mutex0
```

The main problem with this approach is that there is a tangible delay between the lines labelled `[1]` and `[2]`. This means that a `./read` can release `mutex0` at `[1]`, an entire invocation of `./write` can complete, and then `[2]` executes, but will stall indefinitely because `./write` already tried to wake up any sleeping `./read`s before.

Is there no easy way to do what I want, besides using an entire separate full-blown server process? Also, for those curious I want to do this for an application in CGI.

Comment: You could use a semaphore instead of a mutex.

Comment: It seems to me that you want interprocess communication. I suggest reading up on linux's named pipes or [ZeroMQ](http://czmq.zeromq.org/) rather than your ad-hoc scheme.

Comment: Neither of your comments addressed the race condition I pointed out. I know about semaphores, I know about IPC.

Comment: If read releases the semaphore, then write signals it before read gets to the next line, the semaphore will be at 1 and read will continue through. Is there a different problem?

Comment: First off, what you said doesn't make sense if we simply replace `mutex0` above with a semaphore. I think what you mean is to use a second semaphore, so let's call it `semaphore0` and `semaphore1`, where `semaphore0` replaces `mutex0` above, and `semaphore1` signals `read`. Still doesn't work because `write` does not know how many times to increment `semaphore1`, because any number of `read`s can be sleeping, If you still think you're right, then feel free to post a more concrete example of your rightness.

Comment: Are you now saying that there are multiple readers (but still just one writer)? And if so, do you care whether multiple readers process the same resource version? Or do you insist that every reader attempts to process as many versions as possible? All these different possible constraints require different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the program flow for the reader is incorrect. You need some sort of locking mechanism to prevent writes while one or more reads are in progress, and some sort of wakeup mechanism to notify readers whenever a write is completed.

Your program flow for the writer(s) is okay:

```
    # Initial read of file contents
    Obtain lock
        Read file
    Release lock

    # Whenever wishes to modify file:
    Obtain lock
        Modify file
        Signal readers
    Release lock
```

The program flow for the reader(s) should be:

```
    # Initial read of file contents
    Obtain lock
        Read file
    Release lock

    # Wait and respond to changes in file
    On signal:
        Obtain lock
            Read file
        Release lock    
        Do something with modified file contents
```

---

If there is only one reader, then a mutex ([`pthread_mutex_t`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_init.3p.html)) in shared memory (accessible to all writers and the reader) suffices; otherwise, I recommend using an rwlock ([`pthread_rwlock_t`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_rwlock_init.3p.html)) instead. For waking up any waiting readers, broadcast on a condition variable ([`pthread_cond_t`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_init.3p.html)). The difficulty, of course, is setting up that shared memory.

---

Advisory file locking and the [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) interface is also sufficient. Readers install a fanotify `FAN_MODIFY` mark, and simply wait for the corresponding event. Writers do not need to co-operate, except for the use of an advisory lock (which exists only to stop readers from reading while the file is modified).

Unfortunately, the interface currently requires the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability, which you definitely do not want random CGI programs to have.

---

Advisory file locking and the [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) interface is sufficient, and I believe the most appropriate for this, when both readers and writers open and close the file for each set of operations. The program flow for this case for the reader(s) is:

```
Initialize inotify interface
Add inotify watch for IN_CREATE and IN_CLOSE_WRITE for "file"

Open "file" read-only
    Obtain shared/read-lock
        Read contents
    Release lock
Close "file"

Loop:
    Read events from inotify descriptor.
    If IN_CREATE or IN_CLOSE_WRITE for "file":
        Open "file" read-only
            Obtain shared/read-lock
                Read contents
            Release lock
        Close "file"
        Do something with file contents
```

The writer is still just

```
    # Initial read of file contents
    Open "file" for read-only
        Obtain shared/read-lock on "file"
            Read contents
        Release lock
    Close "file"

    # Whenever wishes to modify file:
    Open "file" for read-write
        Obtain exclusive/write-lock
            Modify file
        Release lock
    Close "file"
```

Even if the writers do not obtain the lock, the readers will be notified when a writer closes the file; the only risk is that another set of changes is written (by another lock-spurning modifier) while the readers are reading the file.

Even if a modifier replaces the file with a new one, the readers get correctly notified when a new one is ready (either renamed/linked on top of the old one, or the new file creator closes the file). It is important to note that if the readers keep the file open, their file descriptors will not magically jump to the new file, and they will only see the old (probably deleted) contents.

---

If it is for some reason important that readers and writers do not close the file, the readers can still use inotify, but an `IN_MODIFY` mark instead, to be notified whenever the file is truncated or written to. In this case, it is important to remember that if the file is then replaced (renamed over, or deleted and recreated), the readers and writers will not see the new file, but will operate on the old, now invisible-in-the-filesystem file contents.

The program flow for the reader:

```
Initialize inotify interface
Add inotify watch for IN_MODIFY for "file"

Open "file" read-only
    Obtain shared/read-lock
        Read contents
    Release lock

    Loop:
        Read events from inotify descriptor.
        If IN_CREATE or IN_CLOSE_WRITE for "file":
            Obtain shared/read-lock on "file"
                Read contents
            Release lock
            Do something with file contents
```

The program flow for the writer is still almost the same:

```
    # Initial read of file contents
    Open "file" for read-only
        Obtain shared/read-lock on "file"
            Read contents
        Release lock
    Close "file"

    Open "file" for read-write

    # Whenever writer wishes to modify the file:
    Obtain exclusive/write-lock
        Modify file
    Release lock
```

---

It may be important to note that the inotify events occur after the fact. There is usually some small latency, which might depend on the load on the machine. So, if prompt response to file changes is important for the system to work correctly, you may have to go with a mutex or rwlock and a condition variable in shared memory approach instead.

In my experience, these latencies tend to be shorter than the typical human reaction interval. Therefore, I consider -- and I suggest you do so too -- the inotify interface fast and reliable enough at human timescales; not so at millisecond and sub-millisecond machine timescales.